# Multiple setIntervals at once

Tags: javascript

I am currently leanring JavaScript and was messing around with the setInterval function. I have a function that uses two setIntervals functions to change between two different pictures. Now I am trying to use clearInterval to get it to stop.

Here is my functions:

```js
function changePic(){
  document.puppy.src = "puppy2.jpg";
}

function changePicBack(){
  document.puppy.src = "puppy1.jpg";
}

function changeBetween(){
  var puppyChange = setInterval(changePic, 2000);
  var puppyChange2 = setInterval(changePicBack, 3000);
 }
```

I am having this executed via a button like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Change Between" onclick="changeBetween();" />
```

Is there a simple way I can create a clearInterval function that will stop both set interval functions and have it run from a button?

Comment: Simple. Don't use two setIntervals.

Comment: Make `puppyChange` and `puppyChange2` global.

Comment: @AndrewLi nope.

Comment: Have you had a look here for ideas:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp ?  setInterval returns an id that you need to pass to clearInterval, so you do need to store those values for later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function() {

  var puppy = document.getElementById("puppy"), // Collect your image element
    button = document.getElementById("button"), // Collect your button element
    images = [
      "http://placehold.it/100x100/0bf",
      "http://placehold.it/100x100/fb0",
      "http://placehold.it/100x100/f0b"
      // Need more? add more
    ],
    tot = images.length, // how many puppies we have?
    c = 0, // current image index counter
    itv, // the interval
    isPlaying = false;

  function anim() { // Not exactly an anim.. but I'm sure you'll rock this out!
    c = ++c % tot; // Increment counter and reset to 0 if exceeds tot
    puppy.src = images[c]; // Use the image matching current index
  }

  function play() {
    isPlaying = true;
    itv = setInterval(anim, 2000);
    button.value = "Pause";
  }

  function stop() {
    isPlaying = false;
    clearInterval(itv);
    button.value = "Play";
  }

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      stop();
    } else {
      play();
    }
  });

}());
```

```html
<img id="puppy" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/0bf">
<input id="button" type="button" value="Play" />
```